# How to define geographic boundaries and restrict the app usage like in Uber

Tags: android, ios, node.js, swift, google-maps

I'm building a mobile app which is a ride-sharing app like Uber.

- Now when uber comes to a country, it's not available to the whole country at once. It opens its doors only to a specific region.
- Even when operating in multiple regions, they can set different rates per region.

Now I want to implement this feature in my app. Basically, what I need is,

- To identify the driver is in a specific geographic region set by the system and customize his experience.

Our backend is written in NodeJS and the app is in native Android (Java)and iOS (Swift). So, how can I implement this feature?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this is a good question for S.O...

Comment: Look at the boundaries in google maps API.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "Circle" on your specific region (give it a radius with a center coordinates basically). Get coordinates of the driver from the client and check if he is in the Circle on the backend.

This is probably the easiest way to achieve what you need.